# IBAction Method not being called when button is pushed. But View controller is being pushed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null, push, ibaction

I am attempting to pass information from one `viewController` to another using a push `segue` with an `IBAction` button named `*line`. However from what I can tell this method is not being called and the NSLog(@"%@", see); I inserted to test the method is not displaying any message. Here is some code for the first `viewController`.

`DetailController.m`

```
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "VideoController.h"
#import "Helper.h"

@interface DetailController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet VideoController *videoViewController;
@end

@implementation DetailController
@synthesize city, ClubName, Price, Vip, Promo, remain,p,deal,money,camera,tweet,post;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.videoViewController = [[VideoController alloc] init];
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1400)];
[super viewDidLoad];
UIImage *highlightedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"];
 UIImage *highlightedButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter2.png"];

[Helper customizeBarButton:self.tweet image:highlightedButtonImage highlightedImage:highlightedButtonImage2];

UIImage *faceButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIImage *faceButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook2.png"];

[Helper customizeBarButton:self.post image:faceButtonImage highlightedImage:faceButtonImage2];

UIImage *taxiButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"taxi.png"];
 UIImage *taxiButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"taxi2.png"];

[Helper customizeBarButton:self.taxi image:taxiButtonImage highlightedImage:taxiButtonImage2];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
UIFont *labelFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"King Kikapu" size:15.0];
UIFont *myFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:20.0];
UIFont *myFont2=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:35.0];
UIFont *titleFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Pornstar" size:50.0];
NSString * name= self.city.clubName;
NSString * line= self.city.clubLine;
NSString * description= self.city.promo;
NSString * price= self.city.price;
NSString *ipCam= self.city.camera;

remain.font=labelFont;
remain.text=@"VIP Remaining :";
p.font=labelFont;
p.text=@"Price :";
money.font=myFont;

deal.font=labelFont;
deal.text=@"Promotions :";

ClubName.font=titleFont;
ClubName.text=name;
Vip.font=myFont2;
Vip.text=line;
Price.font=myFont2;
Price.text=price;
Promo.font=myFont;
Promo.text=description;



}
- (IBAction)PostFacebook:(id)sender {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController * facebook= [[SLComposeViewController alloc]init];

    facebook= [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [facebook setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm heading to"]];
    [self presentViewController:facebook animated:YES completion:nil];

    [facebook setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        NSString * output;
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                output=@"Action Cancelled";
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                output=@"Post Succesful";
            default:
                break;
        }
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
}}

- (IBAction)PostTwitter:(id)sender {
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet= [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"I'm heading to"];
    [self presentViewController: tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)line:(id)sender {
NSString *see=self.city.camera;
NSLog(@"%@", see);

UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
self.videoViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page3"];
self.videoViewController.city.camera= self.city.camera;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.videoViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

As a test I inserted `NSLog(@"%@", see);` into the `IBAction` method but this is not returning any value

`DetailController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VideoController.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

@class City;

@interface DetailController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *taxi;

@property (strong,nonatomic) City *city;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ClubName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Vip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Price;

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * camera;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Promo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *remain;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *p;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *deal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *money;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *tweet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *post;

- (IBAction)line:(id)sender;

@end
```

Thanks for any suggestions on why this method is not being called when the button is pushed

Comment: your `IBAction` is being called actually, as you said you can see null being returned in the `NSLog`, which means it is entering the `IBAction line`.

Comment: no I apologize what I said was misleading I did not mean that it is returning null it actually is returning no message at all

Comment: Check the name and case of the `IBAction` and the selector typed in the button, as well as its class. It should be exactly the same at both places.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for your IBAction to NOT get called is when the button is not appropriately connected to it. Double check that in the connections inspector.